# Data validation on model layer?

Tags: django, django-models, django-forms, django-views

How do I validate data on model layer in Django without modelform? 
Do I have to override some functions? 
Suppose I have a CharField in a model class, what function should I override to validate input's data type?

I'm new to django. Sorry if the question is not specific.

Comment: you can override the models save function

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You can add validators to your model fields: https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.8/ref/validators/#writing-validators From the docs:

```
from django.db import models
from django.core.exceptions import ValidationError

def validate_even(value):
    if value % 2 != 0:
        raise ValidationError('%s is not an even number' % value)

class MyModel(models.Model):
    even_field = models.IntegerField(validators=[validate_even])
```

Answer (score 4):

**You can use [`Model.clean()`](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.8/ref/models/instances/#django.db.models.Model.clean) to provide data validation on model layer.**

As per Django docs:

> `Model.clean()`
>   This method should be used to provide custom model
>   validation, and to modify attributes on your model if desired.
>
> This method should be overridden to perform custom validation on your
>   model.

**For validating different types of fields, you can use [validators.](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.8/ref/validators/#module-django.core.validators)**

> A `validator` is a callable that takes a value and raises a
>   `ValidationError` if it doesn’t meet some criteria. Validators can be
>   useful for re-using validation logic between different types of
>   fields.

**Difference between using `validators` and overriding`Model.clean()`:**

Validators only validate the input, they don't return the desired format. If the input was invalid, it will just raise a [`ValidationError`](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.8/ref/exceptions/#django.core.exceptions.ValidationError).

Clean methods both validate and return a value which might be a slightly modified value depending on the requirements.